# Python: Scraping data who are not loaded without scrolling from Gitlab

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have a script which scrape commits from gitlab repository, for example:

```
import urllib.request
import bs4 as bs
url = 'https://gitlab.com/rzkn/curl/-/commits/master'
source = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
descrp = [description.text for description in 
         soup.find_all('a', class_="commit-row-message item-title js-onboarding-commit-item")]
```

So everything works fine, but when there is a more than 40 commits, only 40 is displayed when page is loaded. To get rest ot them, you have to scroll down page. After inspecting the network you can find other link: `https://gitlab.com/rzkn/curl/-/commits/master?limit=40&offset=40`, but it redirects to page with missing commits. Is there a way to get all data in 1 request?

Comment: Have you considered simply cloning the repository and extracting the list of commits using git? Might be a simpler approach to achieve the same end goal of getting the list of commits

Comment: @Omer to be honest, app is created in Django where user inputs correct link to project's commits and then data are scraped, so I think it will be much harder to add merge Django and git, but I can be wrong

Comment: You can use a Python git wrapper like dulwich. Clone the repo into a temporary directory, parse it, much simpler than relying on a non-stable gitlab infinite scroll which might potentially change with every gitlab update.